# Cannot remove right inset of separator below header of grouped UITableView when using accessory in cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessoryview

The separator between the header and first cell has a right inset of about 10-15px that I am trying to remove. This inset goes away when I remove the accessory view from the cell. This seems like an annoying glitch more than anything. Anyone solve this issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution?